# Regex matching excluding a specific context

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to search a string for words within single quotes, but only if those single quotes are not within parentheses.

Example string:
`something, 'foo', something ('bar')`

So for the given example I'd like to match `foo`, but not `bar`.

After searching for regex examples I'm able to match within single quotes (see below code snippet), but am not sure how to exclude matches in the context previously described.

```
string line = "something, 'foo', something ('bar')";
Match name = Regex.Match(line, @"'([^']*)");
if (name.Success)
{
    string matchedName = name.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(matchedName);
}
```

Comment: Do the parentheses immediate surround the single quotes? Ie. should `(text 'foo' text)` match for "foo"?

Comment: Regex101.com is a great site for testing a regular expression to find out if it functions the way you expect.

Comment: @Woot: Regex101 does not support .NET regex. To test .NET regex, Ultrapico Expresso tool is very good.

Comment: They may not always immediately surround the single quotes.  For example if the string to search was `('a','b','c') I would not want to match either a, b, or c.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using lookahead instead (see it [live](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5C()%27%5Cw%2B%27(%3F!%5C))&i=something%2C%20%27foo%27%2C%20something%20(%27bar%27))) using:

```
(?<!\()'([^']*)'(?!\))
```

Or with C#:

```
string line = "something, 'foo', something ('bar')";
Match name = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<!\()'([^']*)'(?!\))");
if (name.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get what you need is to use an alternation group and match and capture what you need and only match what you do not need:

```
\([^()]*\)|'([^']*)'
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C(%5B%5E()%5D*%5C)%7C%27(%5B%5E%27%5D*)%27&i=something%2C%20%27foo%27%2C%20something%20(%27bar%27))

**Details**:

- `\(` - a `(`
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)`
- `|` - or
- `'` - a `'`
- `([^']*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ chars other than `'`
- `'` - a single quote.

In C#, use `.Groups[1].Value` to get the values you need. See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/CkrJyR):

```
var str = "something, 'foo', something ('bar')";
var result = Regex.Matches(str, @"\([^()]*\)|'([^']*)'")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

Another alternative is the one mentioned by Thomas, but since it is .NET, you may use *infinite-width lookbehind*:

```
(?<!\([^()]*)'([^']*)'(?![^()]*\))
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5C(%5B%5E()%5D*)%27(%5B%5E%27%5D*)%27(%3F!%5B%5E()%5D*%5C))&i=something%2C%20%27foo%27%2C%20something%20(%27bar%27)%20(%27a%27%2C%27b%27%2C%27c%27)%20%27bar%27).

**Details**:

- `(?<!\([^()]*)` - a negative lookbehind failing the match if there is `(` followed with 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` up to
- `'([^']*)'` - a quote, 0+ chars other than single quote captured into Group 1, and another single quote
- `(?![^()]*\))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` followed with `)` right after the `'` from the preceding subpattern.

Since you'd want to exclude `'`, the same code as above applies.

Comment: I appreciate the in depth explanation, helps me understand your approach.  I'm trying to understand the differences between the two solutions: what advantage does infinite-width lookbehind provide?

Comment: Infinite width lookbehind allows subpatterns quantified with `*` and `+`. You may fail or require a subpattern to appear further before the pattern you need than immediately before it.